# Are there companies which create commercial molecular dynamics / monte carlo simulations?

Tags: monte-carlo, molecular-dynamics

I would like to know if there is a commercialization of simulations? Or is it only in academic usage?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! As posed, the question is too broad; the short answer is yes. MD is used in developing pharmaceuticals, for instance.

Comment: I know that the answer is YES. Because I know about this company: http://www.avtechscientific.com/. Also, I know this company does not do any significant money from the simulations. Can anyone name such companies?

Answer (score 1):

One example of a commercial MD code that comes to mind is Desmond, which is licensed by Schrödinger, LLC, and was produced by D. E. Shaw research. It is available for non-commercial use by academics, although the impression I get from talking to colleagues active in MD research is that they prefer LAMMPS and GROMACS, which are open-source, community efforts.

Comment: I think You misunderstood the OP -- rlib doesn't ask about commercial MD software, but for examples of commercial MD usage (i.e. any proofs MD was used for drug design and so on).

Comment: D.E. Shaw also does protein folding research, so I presume this post still answers the question in a roundabout way. If the question is really about industrial applications of MD, that's a bit broad; it would be akin to asking if the finite element method is used commercially, or if CFD is used commercially.

Comment: Adobe is right. I want to know if MD is used commercially. For example, some chemical manufacturer A may want to know diffusion coefficient of chemical X in chemical Y. Instead of conducting real experiments, the manufacturer asks company B to estimate the coefficient and B does it for A as it has enough computational power/personal/software.